Fuse/breaker box question
My house was built in the 60s. I have a breaker box inside and a fuse box outside. The fuse box houses two fuses. If the fuse is blown, will it affect my house or my breaker box? Is it normal to have both?

Can you post photos of everything involved please? Also, is the fuse box near your watt-hour (electric) meter at all?

Is it close to an AC unit?  60s were not known to have an outside house disconnect, so a guess it was added for a recent installed AC unit/outside electrical device.

@crip659 - a fuse box (with actual fuses) seems unlikely for a recent install (that is past 40+ years).

@JonCuster      Pictures will probably answer the question.  Some disconnect boxes have fuses.   OP is saying fuse box.  A real fuse box with a brunch of fuses in it, or something like a fuse box, is the question.
